# Derivative of real functions being equal to zero in arbitrary sets

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose that $f: X \subset \mathbb{R} \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a function such that $$f' \equiv 0,$$
for $X$ any subset, not necessarily interval. So is $f$ constant? For in the case of interval we use the mean value theorem to prove.

Comment: Have you tried looking for examples where $X$ is not an interval?

Comment: I tried to look for discrete sets, like the natural ones. But I couldn't resolve it.

Comment: Discrete sets don't really have a notion of derivative on them. Try something that's not an interval yet has continuum so that the derivative makes sense.

Comment: ... such as the union of two disjoint open intervals. Note that the MVT implies that $f$ is constant on each individual interval. Does that mean $f$ is constant on the whole domain?

Comment: It makes sense what you said! For the derivative to make sense at the point, it needs to be accumulation. Hence, the result follows for the case of intervals.

Comment: Consider a specific case. Say $X = (0,1) \cup (2,3)$. Then $f$ is defined on a neighborhood of all its points, so there is no problem in defining $f'$. But it is also not an interval. Can you figure out a way for $f' \equiv 0$ without being constant on all of $X$?